Problems while trying to compile a program with cmake
We have a program named: xyano_prorate.c
This code  We need to run through it with Sonarcube to identify potential coding errors, because after migration it is showing segmentation error in the core dump file.
To analyce this program with sonar I need to compile it: I am trying to compile this program named xyano_prorate.c with cmake in order to check it later with sonarqube.
I have create this: CMakeLists.txt :
message("------------------------------")
message(" ...  Building example    ...")
message("------------------------------")


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

# The name of the executable will be : "xyano_prorate_project"
# When project(..) invoked the variable "PROJECT_NAME" will 
# have the value "xyano_prorate_project"
project(xyano_prorate_project DESCRIPTION "Testing program" LANGUAGES C)

# Set two new variables: one for src path and another for include path
# (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR is set automatically when project(...) invoked
# its value is the path to the called CMakeLists.txt file)
set(SRC_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(INC_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers)

# Nexts adds the target (executable) name and its source files
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_DIR}/xyano_prorate.c)

# Specifies the include directories for the target
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${INC_DIR}"/headers)

The cmake is working:
$ cmake -S .. -B ../build
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:23:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at column 63
  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
------------------------------
 ...  Building example    ...
------------------------------
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /builds/analytics/tam/xyanomi/target_dir/build

but when I launch the build it fails:
$ /builds/group/analytics/mis/MIS-xyanomi/build-wrapper/build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir "${BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR}" cmake --build build/ --config Release
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'strlwr':
xyano_prorate.pgc:617:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'tolower' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
xyano_prorate.pgc:292:1: note: include '<ctype.h>' or provide a declaration of 'tolower'
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'strupr':
xyano_prorate.pgc:626:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'toupper' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
xyano_prorate.pgc:626:13: note: include '<ctype.h>' or provide a declaration of 'toupper'
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'amountFC':
xyano_prorate.pgc:2553:13: warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void
xyano_prorate.pgc:2509:8: note: declared here
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'unloadtkt':
xyano_prorate.pgc:11002:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getcwd'; did you mean 'getw'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
xyano_prorate.pgc:11013:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'chdir' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'unload_le_reste':
xyano_prorate.pgc:11864:10: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'BkgClass' [-Wimplicit-int]
xyano_prorate.pgc:11865:5: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'stpo' [-Wimplicit-int]
xyano_prorate.pgc:11866:5: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'operant' [-Wimplicit-int]
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'main':
xyano_prorate.pgc:13479:5: warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void
xyano_prorate.pgc:13093:5: note: declared here
xyano_prorate.pgc: In function 'parcours_Hubs_Voyages':
xyano_prorate.pgc:817:7: warning: '__builtin_memcpy' writing 6 bytes into a region of size 5 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
xyano_prorate.pgc:634:41: note: destination object 'ArrTime1' of size 5
[100%] Linking C executable xyano_prorate_project
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o: in function `RollBackOrCommit':
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'

And I found tons of "undefined reference" errors:
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o:xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0xd5): more undefined references to `ECPGget_sqlca' follow
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o: in function `RollBackOrCommit':
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `ECPGtrans'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `ECPGtrans'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o: in function `parcours_Hubs_Voyages':
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x8ac): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x8b8): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0xa8f): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o: in function `Enreg_in_Historique':
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x140c): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x149d): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x1562): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x1618): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x1b98): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o:xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x1e14): more undefined references to `ECPGdo' follow
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o: in function `Voyage_et_Destination_eScan':
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x1e20): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x1e93): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xyano_prorate_project.dir/src/xyano_prorate.c.o: in function `Getpfm':
xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x48c6): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x48dc): undefined reference to `ECPGget_sqlca'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x4982): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x4a02): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'
/usr/bin/ld: xyano_prorate.c:(.text+0x4a7a): undefined reference to `ECPGdo'

Can anybody help me?

Have you ever tried to understand/search the warnings and the errors you got? A warning implicit declaration is about your C code. Without viewing that code we could only repeat what the warning message tells you: include the proper header file. An error undefined reference is about your C code and/or linking it with the proper libraries. There is that question on Stack Overflow about common cases of such error.

@Tsyvarev This code has not ben written by me. Has been written by developers some years ago, and they are not in the Company now. Now I am the devops and I need to scan the code with sonarqube because dev team told me they had problems in the code. The compilation in the beggining was done with a dmake script and I am trying to create something similar with cmake.

Whoever has written the code, your question post lacks for details, without which it is impossible to answer it. The most straightforward way: pretend that the code is yours and you compile it for the first time. Take the first warning/error message, and try to understand and solve it. Then go to the next message, and so on.

Alternative way implies that your are very familiar with the original build system (dmake) and understand how original script affects on the compilation/linking process. In that case you may try to replicate those effects in CMake script. When following that way you could compare command lines generated by dmake and CMake and check whether they differ in important aspects. Understanding of what is important for compilation/linking or not requires non-beginner knowledge in that area. Having such knowledge you should be able to provide more details concerning the errors you got.

Doesn't your legacy program have its own build system akready?  Surely it does, and it works (better than your CMake build system, at least), because you wouldn't reach the point of getting segfaults if you couldn't build the program.  I have no clue, then, why you are trying to write a new build system for it, but if you insist on that then surely your best bet would be to let the original one be your guide.

@JohnBollinger I need to write again the build because I need to use build-wrapper with sonar. And build-wrapper use cmake to build.

Sonar's build wrapper does not require CMake.  One of its main objectives is to work with projects' existing build systems.  There are things it doesn't support, but chances are good that it would support your project's original build system.

Your CMakeLists.txt does not specify any of the libraries
that your target diano_prorate_project depends on, so they are
not linked, so all of your program's references to things
defined in these libraries are undefined references at linktime.
Read the documentation of target_link_libraries

@JohnBollinger thank you very much for your suggestion!!!, finally I have use dmake and I have been able to build and check it in sonar :)

Use linker flags. You are getting undefined reference ECPGget_sqlca which is part of libecpg. So condition your cmake to include linkers while compiling.
Example:
gcc -o your_executable your_source.c -lecpg -lpq

Where -lecpg and -lpq are linkers which are telling your compiler that these libraries need to be included while compiling.
Hope this helps!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
